# Is it possible to use Google+ Domains API to access a user not part of a Domain?

Tags: python-2.7, api, google-plus, google-oauth

Hello to anyone who has any suggestion to help,

QUESTIONS:

Is it possible to use use the 'Google+ Domains API' to access a Non-Domain Google+ profile?

For Non-Domain associated Google+ accounts accounts, are only 'Google+ API's' able to be used?

Is there a way the following could be accomplished using Standard OAuth 2.0 client credentials instead of a Service Account?

BACKGROUND:

I'm trying to use the Google+ Domains API for Python to upload .jpg images from a Linux device, and insert to my personal Google+ profile/account.

This account is not part of a Domain and no other Google+ users' data will be accessed by my application. I've created a Service Account and PKCS 12 Key with 'Owner' permission that I use for authorization. NOTE That I did not create Domain Wide Delegation of Authority, because I believe there is no Domain associated with my Personal Google+ account.

```
Getting Error 403 trying to access Google+ Domains using a Service Account

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting 
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/plusDomains/v1/people/me/media/cloud?
uploadType=multipart&alt=json returned "Forbidden">
```

The “Forbidden” error is returned when executing the media().insert() to the collection 'cloud'. Here is the python code that I assembled from examples I found on the Developers Guides.

```
import httplib2
import pprint
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from oauth2client import client
from httplib2 import Http

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.media.upload',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write']

def main(argv):

f = file('Trebor NAO Access-c35352d48d33.p12', 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials('trebor-nao-access-service-659@trebor-nao-access.iam.gserviceaccount.com', key, SCOPES)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build(“plusDomains”, “v1”, http=http)

try:
  user_id = 'me'

  print('Uploading a picture of a box of MiniWheats cereal')
  result = service.media().insert(
      media_body = 'MiniWheats.jpg',
      body = {'displayName': 'MiniWheats.jpg'},
      userId = user_id,
      collection = 'cloud',
  ).execute()
  print('result = %s' % pprint.pformat(result))

  media_id = result.get('id')
  print('MediaID of MiniWheats.jpg: %s' % media_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

Any advice you can give is greatly appreciated.

Robert Dixey